# Filter dataframe based on another data frame scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Currently I am doing:

```
val DF = sqlSession.sql("select itemIdDig as itemId, "
      + "title"
      + "timestamp as time "
      + "from itemTable ")

val tempDF = sqlSession.sql("select itemIdDig as itemId "
      + "from itemTable "
      + "group by itemIdDig HAVING count(*) >= 10 ").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()


//keep itemIds which are not in DF
DF.filter(!col("itemId").isin(tempDF  : _*)).toDF
```

But this is very slow. Can someone suggest me any better ways to achieve this? Basically I am looking from rows which is not in `tempDF` (I tried with group by having which gives me unique `itemId` but I want to preserve the duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just semi join:

```
DF.join(tempDF,  Seq("itemId"), "leftanti")
```

Comment: care to explain semi join ?

Comment: I think it is "left_anti. It gives me different size with the way I do and ur way.